# Exporting Private Keys for wallet in Multibit

Tags: private-key, multibit

My computer just got formatted, and so did my wallet. I had imported the private keys from my wallet a week back. Can I just load that again into multibit, and get my bitcoins back?

I have also had several transactions after I imported it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The private keys unlock your wallet, which will be synchronised to the network. You then have access to the wallet, **with** the bitcoins before and after the back-up of the private keys, just the balance [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info) says you have. So no need to have an recent back-up of those keys.